# Messages not being added to my MSMQ

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq, netmsmqbinding

I am trying to run a MSMQ service for the 1st time.

I have copied an example from MSDN and I am trying to get it to work.

Everything runs OK and there are no errors.  Yet when I go to inspect my MSMQ there are no message available/added.

I have used the Trace tool SvcTraceViewe.exe and there are no errors reported.

This is my Service defined in a class DLL:

```
public class MotionSaver : IMotionSaver
{
    [OperationBehavior]
    public void MotionFrame(byte[] data)
    {
        // DO I NEED TO PUT ANTHING IN HERE??
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMotionSaver
{
    //IsOneWay=true denotes that there will no return message from the server to the client.
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void MotionFrame(byte[] data);
}
```

This is my Server host which calls the above DLL:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MotionSaver)))
        {
            //Path of the Queue. Here we are creating a private queue with the name VishalQ 
            //where all our message would be stored, if server is unavialable.
            string queueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["queueName"];
            //Checking whether the queue exists or not.
            if (!MessageQueue.Exists(queueName))
            {
                //If the queue doesnot exists it will create a queue with the name VishalQ
                //the second parameter false denotes that the queue would be a non transaction queue. If you want that your queue to be 
                //transaction then make the second parameter to true.
                MessageQueue.Create(queueName, true);
            }
            //finally opening the host to server the clients.
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Server is up and running on port 32578");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    catch  (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This is my app.config settings in the host app:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="queueName" value=".\private$\MotionSaverTest4" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "SdrConfigExample.e2e" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>


  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="All"/>
    <services>
      <service name="InformedMotion.Motion.MotionSaver" behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior">
        <!--Address attribute specifies the name of the MSMQ Queue.-->
        <endpoint name="motionQ" address="net.msmq://localhost/private/MotionSaverTest4" binding="netMsmqBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="myMSMQ"                
                  contract="InformedMotion.Motion.IMotionSaver">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.msmq://localhost/private/"/>
            <!--Both Mex and HttpBinding uses http://localhost:8888 port-->
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:32578"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <!--The property exactlyOnce=false means that i am using non transactional queue. The property is by default true.-->
      <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="myMSMQ" exactlyOnce="true">
        <!--<binding name="myMSMQ" exactlyOnce="false" durable="false">-->
          <!--
                        If we donot set the security mode to none then the following error occurs.
                        Binding validation failed because the binding's MsmqAuthenticationMode property is set to 
                        WindowsDomain but MSMQ is installed with Active Directory integration disabled. 
                        The channel factory or service host cannot be opened.
                    -->
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!--This is for enabling an exception-->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/></startup></configuration>
```

This is the client app that call the service:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    wsMotionQ.MotionSaverClient ws = new MotionSaverClient();
    ws.MotionFrame(new byte[] { 1 });

    Console.WriteLine("All Wishes sent successfully");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

and this is my client app.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netMsmqBinding>
                <binding name="motionQ">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </netMsmqBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/MotionSaverTest4"
                binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="motionQ" contract="wsMotionQ.IMotionSaver"
                name="motionQ">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I have checked that my message queue has been created.

1). How does a message get added to the queue?  What is the point of an empty method in my service?
2). Why are my messages not being added?

Thanks

N.B.

Changed code to this:

```
[OperationBehavior]
public void MotionFrame(byte[] jpegData)
{
    using (Message msg = new Message())
    {
        msg.BodyStream = new MemoryStream(jpegData);
        msgQMissedData.Send(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just creating the queue, but you're not sending / receiving messages to/from it.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5830/Using-MSMQ-from-C

Comment: hi, I followed teh example on this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/17e8f6/msmq-in-wcf/. It has no code in that function either.  Am I being pedantic in expecting there to be code or should I be using common sense that I need to add code lol?

Comment: Hi, I certainly needed to add the code in my service to add the code (LOL). I finally got it to work by creating the MSMQ manually rather than through code - which makes it work...